# How to pass a string to a function in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, function, arguments, xcode4

I made a method like this:

```
-(void) doSomething:(NSString *)str
{

}
```

I call it like this

```
doSomething(foo);
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work". You might want to be more specific…

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way that you call methods in objective c is like the following

```
[class method:parameter];
```

In your case, to call doSomething, you would do this:

```
[self doSomething:@"foo"];
```

Comment: you must consider WHERE the method IS.  in case you have NOT created any methods (which is the case) you use [self ...].  if you have a class that contains the method, you use [methodName ...].  UPVOTED! :)

Answer (score 7):

That is because `doSomething` is a method of an Objective-C class. The C syntax for function calls doesn't apply here and you need an instance to call it on, e.g.:

```
[instance doSomething:foo];
```

I strongly recommend to read through Apples [The Objective-C programming language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).